# Selecting a package in Xilinx ISE project: FPGA Spartan 3 Device XC3S200

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan

While creating project in Xilinx ISE, we have to select a package in project setting after choosing Family and device. Could any one help me, how I can select/know the package in Xilinx ISE project setting for FPGA Spartan 3 Device XC3S200. Thanks in advance

Comment: No. We cannot give you a link or hints to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XC3S200 is available in four different physical IC packages -- the VQG100, TQG144, PQG208, and FTG256 packages. Each of these packages has a different number of pins, so ISE needs to know which one you are using.

We have no way of knowing which package your board is using -- you'll need to look at the board yourself. The package type will be printed on the surface of the FPGA. For example, here's how it would be printed on the FTG256 package (from [Spartan-3 FPGA Family: Introduction and Ordering Information](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds099.pdf)):

[image]

If you don't have a board yet and you just need to start a project for testing, pick a package arbitrarily. You can change it later.